# Image Styles Not Generating Thumbnails/Previews

Tags: files, media, configuration

I have File Browser installed on my website.  The module info can be found here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/file_browser

When I go to browse for pictures, there are no images. You can see what I see below:

[image: Lack of Pictures]

Below, you can see "WHY" it is not loading. 
[image: Thumbnails not Found]

It seems to think that the system should have generated thumbnails and it is trying to reference those thumbnails.  However, the files have not been created.

`/sites/default/files/styles/file_entity_browser_thumbnail/public/md-slider-image/slide-corporate-3.jpg?itok=O25-iC4D`

My next thought was that maybe the GD manipulation tool was not enabled and the system needed that to generate the thumbnails.  I checked using command line and that program is installed.

```
GD Support => enabled 
GD headers Version => 2.2.4 
GD library Version > => 2.2.4
```

After further review, I went ahead and discovered that the "image style" functionality of Drupal is what is supposed to be generating the images. So, I went and just tried to use the "normal" image style functionality by adding an image field to a node and attempting to apply a style in "display settings."  When I did this, it did not work.  So, it seems the issue lies with "Image styles."

The most obvious solution would seem to be that I do not have the permissions set correctly.

I went to `/sites/default/files/` and the owner is www-data (apache) and the "octal" is 0777. I also made sure to apply these permissions "recursively" so it would copy down to any sub directories.  Nothing seemed to change after doing that.  I also am not getting any errors that I can find.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix or where an error might be generated that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you checked directory and file permissions to make sure that they are writable by the server?

Comment: Ismail, I did check and I went ahead and updated my question to reflect what I did. The directory where they are supposed to be generated has apache as owner and "0777" set as permission.  I think that is as liberal as it can possibly be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for the image style issue was to alter the HTACCESS in that folder so it would allow apache to use image files.

I can also confirm that it WILL NOT work if you do not have your apache rewrite module turned on.

**Final note** - this will work without the octal being "777" as I mentioned in original post.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for this might also be mod_rewrite not being enabled in apache